# How to convert Recursive Approach to iterative one(Super Reduced String)?

Tags: python-3.x, strings, recursion, iteration

**The Question:**

Steve has a string of lowercase characters in range ascii[‘a’..’z’]. He wants to reduce the string to its shortest length by doing a series of operations. In each operation he selects a pair of adjacent lowercase letters that match, and he deletes them. For instance, the string aab could be shortened to b in one operation.

Steve’s task is to delete as many characters as possible using this method and print the resulting string. If the final string is empty, print Empty String

**Test Case 1 : `aaabccddd`
output 1 : `abd`**

**Test Case 2 : `baab`
output 2 : `Empty String`**

**My Approach:**

```
def check(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if(s[i] == s[i+1]):
            return(False)
    return(True)


def remove(s):
    if(check(s)):
        return(s)
    else:
        for i in range(len(s)-1):
            if(s[i] == s[i+1]):
                if(i+2 < len(s)):
                    return(remove(s[0:i]+s[i+2:]))
                else:
                    return(remove(s[0:i]))

s=list(input())
s2=remove(s)
if(len(s2)>0):
    print(''.join(s2))
else:
    print('Empty String')
```

***But I am confused how to make an iterative approach of this problem.Can anyone help me?***

[Question Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reduced-string/problem)

Answer (score 1):

- First thing first, `check` is a waste of time.
- Why bother with

  ```
          else:
              return(remove(s[0:i]))
  ```

  The new pair suitable for removal may emerge only when you remove something from the midst of the string. When you remove the last two characters, it is not possible, and the entire string is already inspected. Just `return s[0:i]`.
- Now with the small rearrangement we have

  ```
  def remove(s):
      for i in range(len(s)-1):
          if(s[i] == s[i+1]):
              if(i+2 == len(s)):
                  return s[0:i]
              return remove(s[0:i]+s[i+2:])
  ```

  You may notice that even though the recursive call is made in the loop, it is done only once: `return` will prevent the further looping. Let's make it explicit:

  ```
  def remove(s):
      if len(s < 2):
          return s
      for i in range(len(s)-1):
          if(s[i] == s[i+1]):
              break
      if i == len(s):
          return s
      if(i+2 == len(s)):
          return s[0:i]
      return remove(s[0:i]+s[i+2:])
  ```

  Now we have a tail recursive call. It translates to the iterations quite mechanically. The tail recursive form

  ```
  def foo_recursive(x):
      if condition(x):
          return something(x)
      x = modify_argument(x)
      return foo_recursive(x)
  ```

  is equivalent to

  ```
  def foo_iterative(x):
      while !condition(x):
          x = modify_argument(x)
      return something(x)
  ```

  Try to apply this recipe.

  PS: I am not saying that the result is the best (that is the most performant) solution. In fact, there is a better algorithm: after a removal of a pair, do not reinspect the string from the very beginning.